# How to restrict an end user to login only at one device at a time in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session

I have developed an application using Laravel 9 and I want to restrict my endusers to login only at a single device at one time. The end user should not shares his user id and password with other users and login both at one time.

How can I restrict the end user login if same user credentials are already logged in from other machine or location or device??

I did try to save current session id in db with last timestamp of login and delete that same when end user logout. in this case if end user do not logout my previous session does not expire

Comment: Google it. This site is not for getting solution from scratch even if some will still try to help you or at least orient you in the right direction. Still, your question is opinion based => off topic on SO. Anyway, you can restrict to one device by IP, session ID, Generated token,.... save it to your DB or Cache and compare on it in a middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to set a token for each user. When user login make a new token

```
$token = Str::random(32);
```

Use a middleware to check if user token exists in your db or return 401 forbiden.

Check middleware example [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192041/laravel-token-middleware)